# How to join tables only with the latest record in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I want to list all customer with the latest phone number and most recent customer type
the phone number and type of customers are changing periodically so I want the latest record only without getting old values based on the lastestupdate column

Customer:

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+
|latestUpdate| CustID |  AddID    |  TypeID    |
+------------+--------+-----------+-------------
| 2020-03-01 |      1 |    1      |     1     |
| 2020-04-07 |      2 |    2      |     2     |
| 2020-06-13 |      3 |    3      |     3     |
| 2020-03-29 |      4 |    4      |     4     |
| 2020-02-06 |      5 |    5      |     5     |
+------------+--------+------------+----------+
```

CustomerAddress:

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
|latestUpdate| AddID  | Mobile    |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-03-01 |      1 | 66666     |
| 2020-04-07 |      1 | 55555     |
| 2020-06-13 |      2 | 99999     |
| 2020-03-29 |      3 | 11111     |
| 2020-02-06 |      3 | 22222     |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

CustomerType:

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
|latestUpdate| TypeId | TypeName  |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-03-01 |      1 |  First    |
| 2020-04-07 |      1 | Second    |
| 2020-06-13 |      3 | Third     |
| 2020-03-29 |      4 | Fourth    |
| 2020-02-06 |      5 | Fifth     |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

When I tried to join I am always getting duplicated customerID not only the latest record

I want to Display Customer.CustID and CustomerType.TypeName  and CustomerAddress.Mobile

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want what columns in the query?

Comment: Why do not use analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sub-queries for *most recent customer type* and *latest phone number* like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT latestUpdate, CustID, AddID, TypeID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY latestUpdate DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Customer
) AS c
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT latestUpdate, AddID, Mobile,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AddId ORDER BU ltestUpdate DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM CustomerAddress
    ) AS t
        ON c.AddId = t.AddId
    INNER JOIN CustomerType ct
        ON ct.TypeId = c.TypeId
WHERE c.RowNumber = 1
    AND t.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way than using `row_number` would be using `cross apply` together with `top 1` in an ordered subquery:

```
select c.CustId, p.Mobile
from Customer c
  cross apply (
    select top 1 Mobile
    from CustomerAddress a
    where c.CustId = a.AddId
    order by a.latestUpdate
  ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some subqueries :

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customer AS C
       LETF OUTER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY LastestUpdate DESC) AS N
                        FROM   CustomerAddress) AS A
          ON C.CustID = A.CustID AND N = 1
       LETF OUTER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY LastestUpdate DESC) AS N
                        FROM   CustomerType) AS T
          ON C.CustID = T.CustID AND N = 1
```

If you have had used Temporal table which is an ISO SQL Standard feature for data history of table, you will always have the lastest rows inside the main table, old rows stays into history table and can be queried with a time point or date interval restriction.

Answer (score -1):

This is it:

```
select * from (select *,RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY b.AddID    
    ORDER BY b.latestUpdate DESC,
) as rank1
from 
Customer a
left join
CustomerAddress b
on 
a.AddID=b.AddID        
left join
CustomerType c
on
v.TypeId =c.TypeId 
) where rank1=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should join the tables using the "APPLY" operator.
See: [Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)